# Minimal and maximal values in a series

Tags: awk

My problem is the following: I have a file, where in the first column there are group numbers and  in the second column - different values:

```
1 34
1 43
1 6
2 12
2 9
3 57
3 19
3 78
```

What I need is to extract minimal and maximal values for each group:

```
1 6,43
2 9,12
3 19,78
```

I was trying to do it in awk but didn't manage.  What I am doing now is separateing each group in different files and finding min and max there separately. Will be appreciative of any advise of how to do it in one file using awk. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TomFenech thanks for the hint, copied the wrong url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# If we've seen this group before, reassign min and max if necessary:
$1 in min {
  min[$1] = ($2 < min[$1]) ? $2 : min[$1]
  max[$1] = ($2 > max[$1]) ? $2 : max[$1]
  next
}

# First time we've seen this group. Initialize min and max:
{ min[$1] = max[$1] = $2 }

# Output the resulting min and max values. (Order will be
# somewhat random):
END {
  for (i in min) {
      print i " " min[i] "," max[i]
  }
}
```

You can pipe the result into sort if you care about the order:

```
$ awk -f mm.awk file | sort -n
1 6,43
2 9,12
3 19,78
```